# RabbitMQ accepting AMQP connection is slow, more than 8seconds

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmqctl

I am using rabbitmq-server-3.6.6 with Erlang R16B03-1 in CentOS 7. After installing the rabbitmq, and I am trying to use pika to build an rpc server. However, the pika.BlockingConnection() part to connec to 127.0.0.1 is so slow, which more than 8 seconds, which usually should be around 1~5ms.

Here are a list of my rabbitmq-env.conf settings, and pika connection codes:

1. /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: 
   `NODENAME=rabbit@localhost`
   `ulimit -S -n 4096`
2. `def loop_rpc_1():
     import pika, time, uuid
     host = '127.0.0.1'
     port = 5672
     user = 'rpc_user'
     passwd = '123456'
     vhost = '/dev'
     credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(user, passwd)
     list = range(1, 100)
     for i in list:
         start_time = time.time()
         conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host, port, vhost, credentials, ))
         conn.close()
         print(i, time.time() - start_time)`

The output: 
`loop_rpc_1()
1 7.42911958694458
2 5.011636972427368
3 0.008404970169067383
4 0.00924539566040039
5 8.006478071212769
6 2.010906934738159
7 0.008637666702270508
8 0.008483409881591797
9 5.0115368366241455
10 0.00960850715637207
11 0.008922576904296875
12 5.015120506286621
13 8.005479335784912
14 2.011262893676758
15 8.005752325057983
16 2.0079636573791504
17 8.006184816360474
18 2.0097343921661377
19 0.008991718292236328
20 8.00625205039978`

The /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq@localhost.log is like:

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:12 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5344.4> (127.0.0.1:44705 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:14 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5344.4> (127.0.0.1:44705 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:14 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5371.4> (127.0.0.1:44706 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5371.4> (127.0.0.1:44706 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5427.4> (127.0.0.1:44707 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5427.4> (127.0.0.1:44707 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5434.4> (127.0.0.1:44708 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5434.4> (127.0.0.1:44708 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:19 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5441.4> (127.0.0.1:44709 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:27 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5441.4> (127.0.0.1:44709 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:27 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5515.4> (127.0.0.1:44710 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Aug-2017::20:17:29 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5515.4> (127.0.0.1:44710 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)`

3. Besides, commands like `time rabbitmqctl list_users`, `service rabbitmq-server start/stop/status` are also pretty slow.

What is a standard procedure for debugging this sort of issues?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Less likely, but anyway, check whether your connection is under flow control (http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/)

Comment: Thanks pinpain! I will take a look.